# Protractor can't return value from nested function

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm executing Protractor test case and for avoiding duplicities I want to put the same code to function.

I need to get information about visibility of specific element which needs nested function.

This return false, even if this condition is true (hiddenCssValue == "visible")

```
  function subEntriesVisibility(elem) {
    elem.element(by.className('ct-sub-entries')).getCssValue('visibility').then(function (hiddenCssValue) {
      if (hiddenCssValue == "visible") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

This return "", even if this condition is true (hiddenCssValue == "visible")

```
  function subEntriesVisibility(elem) {
    var res = "";
    elem.element(by.className('ct-sub-entries')).getCssValue('visibility').then(function (hiddenCssValue) {
      if (hiddenCssValue == "visible") {
        res = true;
      } else {
        res = false;
      }
    });
    return res;
  }
```

I just need to get false if element will be hidden and true if it will be visible. Currently it returns false everytime. e.g. in second block have res filled by true or false

Comment: Have you tried with `getAttribute()` ? instead of `getCssValue`

Comment: Try adding `return` before `elem.element(...`

Comment: @sergey is correct here, your value is being returned only to the function within your `.then`. If you want the result of that promise chain to be returned out of that `subEntriesVisibility` function you need to return the whole chain, starting at the beginning. Then the final value final will be passed all the way back out.

Comment: Also, fyi, I think your function could achieve the same functionality written like `return elem.element(by.className('ct-sub-entries')).getCssValue('visibility')
    .then(hiddenCssValue => hiddenCssValue == "visible");` but I haven't actually tested that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your `return` only exist in the anonymous function passed to `.then`. In order to use does value you need to `return elem.element(...` in `subEntriesVisibility` and invoke `.then` from there. Take a look

```
function subEntriesVisibility(elem) {
    return elem.element(by.className('ct-sub-entries'))
        .getCssValue('visibility').then(function (hiddenCssValue) {
              if (hiddenCssValue == "visible") {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
        });
}

// How to use it
subEntriesVisibility(myElement).then(function(value){
    if (value === true) {
        // do this
    } else {
        // do that
    }
});
```

If you are OK with ES6 and `async/await`, your code could look simpler

```
function subEntriesVisibility(elem) {
    return elem.element(by.className('ct-sub-entries'))
        .getCssValue('visibility')
        .then((hiddenCssValue) => hiddenCssValue === "visible");
}

// How to use it. 
async function run() {
    const value = await subEntriesVisibility(myElement);

    if (value === true) {
        // do this
    } else {
        // do that
    }
}

run();
```

Hope it helps